# Running virt-install inside VM on vmware

Tags: linux, vmware, rhel7, libvirt

I'm trying to run virt-install on Redhat 7 VM ( on ESXi host ).

I'm getting error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# virt-install
ERROR    Host does not support any virtualization options
```

I know I need additional parameters, but it will fail the same.

I have checked the "Hardware virtualization" for the VM cpu and set "CPU/MMU Virtualization" to both HW and both SW no help.

virt-host-validate looks ok:

[root@localhost ~]# virt-host-validate

```
  QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm exists                                   : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible                            : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists                             : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists                               : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller mount-point                  : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller mount-point                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller mount-point                 : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller mount-point                  : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller mount-point                 : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller mount-point                   : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : WARN (No ACPI DMAR table found, IOMMU either disabled in BIOS or not supported by this hardware platform)
   LXC: Checking for Linux >= 2.6.26                                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace ipc                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace mnt                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace pid                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace uts                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace net                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace user                                          : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller mount-point                  : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller mount-point                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller mount-point                 : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller mount-point                  : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller mount-point                 : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller mount-point                   : PASS
   LXC: Checking if device /sys/fs/fuse/connections exists                   : PASS
```

CPU has correct tags (vmx):

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep --color -E "vmx|svm" /proc/cpuinfo
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm invpcid_single tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

kvm is loaded:

```
root@localhost ~]# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             188688  0
kvm                   636969  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              13503  1 kvm
```

What else is missing ? ( I need the virt functional to create live-cd via Lorax livemedia-creator and I really don't want to use solo physical machine for that... )

And yes I have tried to reinstall every virt package already.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like I was missing: libvirt-daemon-kvm